# Hierarchical Use of SharePoint 2013

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-2013, hierarchical

I'm trying to determine the best way to utilize SharePoint 2013 to manage a very large project with a number of hierarchical elements.  I've thought about using cascading/embedded group permissions (doesn't appear to be possible), audience targeting (I'm concerned about user's ability to understand and correctly enter the appropriate target audience), using some kind of session variable fed from a SharePoint list to determine how to characterize entries but then I need a way to auto filter them in lists (seems awfully complex and not sure this will even work).  So I'm wondering if I'm missing a better way to do this.  This being the following:

I have various staff levels: people at the bottom who are located at a site, a person at the site that is the manager, a hub that links various sites, areas that oversee hubs and include an area manager.  I'd like these various people to be able to see only whats relevant to them so for a simple example: a list with a calendar view.  An area lead should be able to see all entries made by his site leads, while a site/hub manager should only be able to see entries made by people under their respective site/hub.  This would work perfect if I could assign groups to groups and then filter the list instead of by [me] by [(some permission filter option)]

There has got to be a simple way to do this, anyone have any ideas?  I think I'm missing some capability of SharePoint 2013 to do something like this and thus am making it harder than it should be.